# Option clash for package inputenc

Tags: packages, input

```
031019manuscript.tex, line 13

LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 \usepackage
                {amsfonts}
The package inputenc has already been loaded with options:
  [utf8]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [latin9]
Adding the global options:
  utf8,latin9
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

Comment: Use just the option corresponding to the encoding of your file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Currently your issue is not reproducible, so it's difficult to find a solution. Could you post a small example document (for example the first 13 lines of your document, and `\begin{document}`, a bit of text, and `\end{document}`) that reproduces the issue?